# Check if object attribute exists in java

Tags: java

E.g.

```
[{
     'name': 'Foo',
     'distance': 2
},{
     'name': 'Bar'
}]
```

This will parsed into a list of objects of this class:

```
 class City {
     public String name;
     public int distance;
 }
```

However for Bar the city object will not have the distance attribute. Can I check for types like I would check for objects? Like:

```
if(city.distance)
```

How can I check if distance is set?

Comment: `if(distance != null)`

Comment: Well... it depends on the parser... If the parser decides to set the distance to 0... But I doubt it would succeed in making an `int` `null`.

Comment: @dystroy like I said, the parser will not set it to 0.

Comment: @artworkadシ In java you don't have `undefined`. It's an `int`. What do you think it can do ?

Comment: You can sign a minus value by default and mb it's better to use getter and setter?)

Comment: Which is your parser? Can you create the class to which the parser should parse your object (e.g. `City`)? If so you can make `distance` as `Integer` to allow `null` value and check for `city.getDistance()==null`

Comment: @dystroy its GSON parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
City city = gson.fromJson(json, City.class);
```

[Custom parse classes are allowed with GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples). Just use `Integer` instead of `int` and check for null value.

Remember that you have to create a `City` class with a void constructor:

```
public class City {

    public Integer distance;
    public String name;

    public City() {/*void constructor*/}

    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Check for `null` using `city.getDistance()==null`

Comment: +1 thank you, tried this and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Integer instead of an int, and check if it is null. The same can be made for other atributes, use a class instead of a raw type.